# Android Notifications: how to post setSmallIcon using custom Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, notifications, icons

I want to post Notification with short text indtead of icon. I plan to do it making own draw into this bitmap. Problem is that setSmallIcon requires resId (I don't want to create tons of predefined bitmaps!), but setLargeIcon value is ignored anyway in Notification bar and is visible only when all notifications are opened.

Can anybody advise a trick? How can I use bitmaps there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. The API only allows for setting the notification's small icon by using a resource, and I assume that was deliberate.

You could use the large icon on Android v3.0+, for which you can use a Bitmap, but it's generally designed to show people/contacts so be careful of what you display there.

I suspect your best option is likely to be to use a custom Notification - at least then you have some flexibility on what you can display
http://www.roman10.net/android-custom-notification-with-progress-bar/

Comment: Thank you, custom notification is in my plan anyway. But small icon itself _required_ to be informative itself, not just show own presense. It seems I have to create many predefined images :(